# Implement admob eu-consent in a react-native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, admob

Has anybody successfully implemented the Admob eu-consent library on a react-native android app? or managed to send the user consent to Admob without the library? How?

I'm using the react-native-firebase module for Admob, unfortunately the developers there aren't considering a solution for this, yet.

After Admob released this library our eCPM dropped at 50% for all users (including for US users).

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Nothing so far :(